# How can I use the a cache manager in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, caching, methods, sulu

I my contoller I try to clear the cache when updating a page

```
protected function mapDataToEntity(array $data, Project $entity): void{
    
    $entity->setName($data['name']);

    $cacheManager = $this->get('sulu_http_cache.cache_manager');
    $cacheManager->invalidatePath($path, $headers);
}
```

I get the error message:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "get" of class
> "App\Controller\Admin\ProjectController". Did you mean to call e.g.
> "cgetAction", "getAction", "getLocale" or "getSecurityContext"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should autowire your cache manager instead of trying to access it from the container.

```
private CacheManager $cacheManager;

public function __construct(CacheManager $cacheManager)
{
    $this->cacheManager = $cacheManager;
}
```

And use it in your method:

```
$this->cacheManager->invalidatePath($path, $headers);
```